# about service perform refresh operations in the background

Tags: android, service, background, onkeydown

I have 3 activity:`Act_1, Act_2 and Act_3`, and a `service:RefreshService`.

I want when the user clicks the home button,`RefreshService` stops refresh operations.

now,i override the `Act_1.onStop()` method to stop refresh,but when `Act_1` start to `Act_2`,the refresh stop too,This is not what I want.

And i override the `Act_1.onKeyDown()` method, it's not good too.

Do you have any good design

Answer (score 0):

So let me understand your requirement.
I think you want to stop your service whenever your application goes in background regardless of if it's going in background from activity A or B or C.

So for this you can follow this approach.

Activity-A
onPause() -> Start a timer task for stopping the service e.g. 15 seconds.
From here on wards either your application can go to HOME screen or Activity B.

Activity-B
onResume() -> Cancel the timer task and service will keep on running.

HOME Screen
Your timer task will trigger and stop the service.

Comment: thank you answer.You understand very correct.but it's not elegant.i want create a AbstractActivity...don't know how

Comment: If you write an abstract activity and all your activities like A,B,C extends that abstract activity but again you have to differentiate either the app is traversing between activities or moving into background. You may think about other solution instead of timer task.